# Console.log() is printing two different values of same variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running a code, I share it with you, it's very simple, in the case of two different `console.log()` commands it is returning two different results.
Here `".filter_me"` class is assigned to an anchors,

```
$(".filter_me").each(
    function(index,value)
    {    
        console.log(index+" is index and "+value+" is value.");
        //output of above line is "0 is index and "http://www.ex.com/2 
        //is value"{for first anchor,http://www.ex.com/ is base url and
        //2 is value of href of first anchor}
        console.log(value);
        //output of above line is <a href="2" class="filter_me">clk</a>
    });
```

So why in first case

`value = http://www.ex.com/2`

and in second case

`value = <a href="2" class="filter_me">clk</a>`

Comment: In the first example the `value` is converted to a string, whereas in the second example the object is logged to the console. I guess this is an issue of object serialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first value is converted to a string because of your other strings in the log.

The second value is the object because it's the only element in the log.